# How to properly enable video autoplay with sound

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, video, autoplay

As an experiment, I wanted to create a video feed like Tik Tok in vue.js.

But I ran into a problem, if I want to turn on autoplay, I have to turn off the sound. At the same time, in order to turn on the sound, the user must interact with the element - but each next video in the feed is one way or another a separate HTML element "video" and there are many such elements, it would be stupid if the user has to turn on the sound on each of the videos.

Please tell me how to approach this problem?

Comment: There's no way around this. It's a limitation in place at browser-level, in order to stop websites spamming annoying video/sounds as soon as the user lands on the site. You would need to amend the flow through your site so that the user needs to click something, or perform some action, in order to start the videos playing.

Comment: @RoRyMcCrossan , I understand that it is impossible to pass the restriction itself (without some hacks). My question was how to do it correctly through one player.

Comment: And why in the web version of Tik Tok when loading the page, the video is played with sound before the user begins to interact with it.

Comment: Chrome (and others) have a whitelist of high popularity of sites that are enabled for autoplay - youtube, and tiktok meet that threshold, but most don't/won't